Confused about part of the Knuth-Liang algorithm for hyphenation
I'm implementing the Knuth-liang algorithm in Lua to create a text-wrapping plugin for Davinci resolve. I've looked at the explanation of the algorithm and there's one part that I don't understand. Here's the part that confuses me from the pyhyphen readme:

Knuths algorithm basically just does pattern matches from the rule set, then applies the matches. The patterns in this case that match are “xa”, “xam”, “mp”, and “pl”. These are actually stored as “x1a”, “xam3”, “4m1p”, and “1p2l2”. Whenever numbers appear between the letters, they are added in. If two (or more) patterns have numbers in the same place, the highest number wins. Here’s the example:

 . e x a m p l e .
    x1a
    x a m3
       4m1p
         1p2l2
-----------------
. e x1a4m3p2l2e .


Finally, hyphens are placed wherever odd numbers appear

Why only odd numbers?

Perhaps, the only purpose of patterns with even numbers is to override smaller odd numbers, thus effectively forbidding hyphenation.

Yes, I think you're right, it's a way of encoding 'don't hyphenate here' into the hyphenation algorithm. It might have been clearer to use, say negative numbers, but that would have made the algorithm more cumbersome, because you'd have to get the absolute value of the number, and then find out if the value was negative. You can tell this was written when CPU cycles were were scarcer.
